# Bootstrap grid scheme vertical align two col-md's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

How do I horizontal align an element in bootstrap grid? In the following example I have a col-md-4 and another col-md-8 and what I want is to vertical align to middle those two col-md's as in picture below.
[image]
**[here is a small fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6395/)**

This is html:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills text-center">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">text1o</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Text5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="col-md-8 v_center">

css
  .v_center { height: 200px;    
              display: flex;    
              align-items: center; }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 outbox">
```

.outbox{height:200px;display: inline-flex;}

.nav-pills{border-top: 1px solid #428BCA;border-bottom: 1px solid #428BCA;margin:auto 0;}